# How do I sort a cloned temp list in a while loop without also sorting the original list(C#)?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, while-loop

I copied an int list into a temporary list in a while loop so I could sort it without sorting the original. For some reason both get sorted when I do this and I don't understand why.

```
public static int sortedSum(List<int> a)
{
    int ans = 0;
    while (a.Count > 0)
    {
        var temp = a;
            
        temp.Sort();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            ans += temp[i] * (i + 1);
        }
        a.RemoveAt(a.Count - 1);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

The Problem I was trying to solve requires me to keep removing the last index spot and then sorting the list. I thought cloning the list would allow me to manipulate the list without messing with the index spots of the original but when I sort the Temp list the original gets sorted as well. I suspect this is a function of the while loop, but if so I'm confused at to why the "a" list would take on the characteristics of the temp list and not vise versa as the "var temp = a;" would suggest.  I was able to work around the problem by converting temp to an int array and sorting that, but I'm still curious as to what's going on here.

Comment: you aren't cloning the list. you are creating a new name/variable for it.

Comment: Is this the Sum over the Sum of the first n elements of a sorted List with a scalar? So, sl[0] + sl[0] + 2*sl[1] + sl[0] + 2*sl[1] + 3*sl[2] + ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I copied an int list into a temporary list

No you didn't - `var temp = a;` does not create a copy of the list - they are referencing the same list.

I would just do

```
var temp = a.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

if you want a separate, sorted list.  There may even be more efficient ways to do what you're trying to do, but your logic is not clear enough to make a better suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! This came from my attempt to solve a HackerRank problem. I'll try to explain but as you can tell, I've still new. Basically you take the list of int (a). you perform a series of equations (s) that involve adding an int from the list, sorting it and multiplying each int by it's position ex. (s1 = a[0] *1) (s2 = a[0] * 1 + a[1] * 2) then adding each series together. I decided to do it backwards working with the full list and eventually going down to the last index spot. There is more wrong with this code than just my original question for sure, but it is what bugged me the most.